# Is there any way to use ReplayingDecoder after an HttpResponseDecoder?

Tags: netty

I am trying to decode the bytes in the contents of an HTTP response into a series of records.  I was hoping to use the ReplayingDecoder in the following pipeline HttpResponseDecoder -> ReplayingDecoder. However, I cannot since ReplayingDecoder.decode() expects a ByteBuf, but the HttpResponseDecoder produces HttpContent objects.  Is there any way to use a ReplayingDecoder in this context?

Comment: Can you tell me why you would need a ReplayingDecoder? What you try to do ?

Comment: The contents of my HTTP response has data of the form ROW ROW ROW ..., where each ROW consists of COLUMN_SIZE COLUMN_BYTES.  I wanted to use the ReplayingDecoder to produce a list of ROW objects from the HTTP response contents

Answer (score 0):

Jus use the HttpObjectAggregator. This will make sure you only receive FullHttpResponse objects which holds the full payload in the ByteBuf.